# sql ssms connect to database engine error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014-express

[image: Getting this error during connect to server. I have installed the Ms SQL 2014 express on my laptop and now I get this error. Please assist]

[image][image][image]

Getting this error during connect to server. I have installed the Ms SQL 2014 express on my laptop and now I get this error. Please assist

Comment: check service is up and running on ur machine ( using services.msc)

Comment: yes, service 'SQLServer (MSSQLSERVER)' to be specific.

Comment: Yes problem is with services. Have posted more images. How can I resolve this as it is disabled already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably not disabled. Its just that you need local admin rights on the machine to change the service status, start it etc. I think that's why the options are greyed out in your screen shots because you aren't currently a local admin.

Once you've got access to the DBMS and SQL Browser services with SQL Express you'll also need to go into SQL Server config tools and enable the TCP protocol.

Finally check local firewall rules. Named instances use dynamic ports. Not 1433 by default. You might also want to set this while in the TCP config.